# En mathématiques, « supposons que » est-il suivi du subjonctif ou de l'indicatif ?

Tags: mathématiques, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

En mathématiques, il est fréquent de supposer. Parfois, lorsqu'on énonce un théorème, on peut lire, par exemple : « *Supposons que f atteint un max ou un min en un point a de I.* » Ou encore : « *Supposons que f atteigne un max ou un min en un point a de I.* »

En cherchant sur le Net le bon temps de verbe à employer, aucun choix définitif ne semble être fait. Une source dira qu'on peut employer l'indicatif alors qu'une autre prétendra qu'on doit absolument employer le subjonctif.

J'ai lu que lorsqu'on suppose quelque chose qui est impossible, on doit employer le subjonctif. Ainsi je croirais que dans l'*énoncé* d'un théorème l'indicatif est acceptable et lors d'une démonstration aussi, à moins que cette dernière ne se fasse par contradiction ?

**Question :** Y a-t-il un standard non ambigu à respecter ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Etant mathématicien, ni l'un ni l'autre ne me choquent et j'emploie les deux un peu au hasard chaque jour.

Cependant, tu as tout à fait raison quant à l'emploi du subjonctif dans les mathématiques : il est quasiment tout le temps utilisé dans les démonstrations par l'absurde, sans doute parce qu'une démonstration par l'absurde repose uniquement sur son hypothèse et donc le choix du subjonctif est là pour souligner cette absurdité. Mais en aucun cas il est interdit d'utiliser l'indicatif! C'est juste moins commun.

Une nouvelle fois, aucun des deux n'est choquant. Le choix des mots de logique est EXTRÊMEMENT important dans un théorème ou une démonstration car c'est là dessus que repose toute la justesse et la cohérence de l'énoncé, mais le choix du subjonctif ou de l'indicatif n'influe en aucun cas sur la justesse d'un théorème.

Answer (score 1):

On ne connaît pas la valeur d'un objet, il dépend d'un autre objet, le subjonctif est recommandé :

> Supposons que *a* soit supérieur à *b*, alors nous pouvons démontrer ....

... ici on a fait une hypothèse sur *a* qui n'est pas connu, l'existence de *a* est subordonnée à celle de *b*.

Cela vient de l'étymologie du mot *subjonctif* : du latin *subjunctivus « attaché sous..., subordonné ».*

On attribut une valeur à cet objet singulier, le présent s'emploie alors :

> Maintenant supposons que *a* est nul, alors la valeur de *b* ...

... ici *a* est connu.

Le subjonctif est de moins en moins utilisé à l'oral et la grammaire mathématique est abstraite, ce qui peut amener à entendre l'indicatif à la place du subjonctif et à effacer ces nuances sans que la question perdent son sens.

Comment: Je ne vois aucune difference, tes deux ememples sont similaires. Aucune différence en pratique. On entend les deux.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez ... oui, on les entend, mais il existe une subtilité sémantique induite par le subjonctif qui invite à choisir l'un ou l'autre, selon que la supposition parle d'un objet relatif ou d'un objet  'étant en soi'. Flugueubluck indique bien que c'est un rare cas où la précision du choix des mots n'est pas absolument nécessaire, et donc que chacun fait à sa guise et donc abandonne le subjonctif sans regret, mais je maintiens cette nuance uniquement pour ceux qui ont envie de [re]découvrir l'emploi de SUPPOSER QUE + ***

Answer (score 0):

Grammaticalement,  il faut utiliser le subjonctif dans cette construction de phrase avec 'que'. Je pense que l'utilisation de l'indicatif est un abus de langage. Personnellement,  je trouve que 'Supposons que i est grand' sonne faux.

Comment: Parfois, on en arrive à dire "supposons i plus grand que j". Ca a beau sonner faux, c'est rentré dans la catégorie abus de langage couramment utilisé, car lorsque l'on écrit ceci en langage mathématique, cela donne : Supposons (i>j). La grammaire importe peu comme je le disais au dessus.

Comment: @Flugueubluck la phrase "supposons i plus grand que j" ne pose pas de problème vu qu'il n'y pas le verbe être ni à l'indicatif, ni au subjonctif ;)