# Dois-je utiliser le subjonctif après « Supposons que » ?

Tags: grammaire, mathématiques, mode-grammatical

Je ne sais pas si on doit utiliser l'indicatif ou le subjonctif ici. Laquelle des phrases ci-dessous est correcte ?

> Supposons que X et Y **sont** [des espaces de Banach](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_de_Banach).
>
> Supposons que X et Y **soient** des espaces de Banach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A -** S'il s'agit ici d'une *hypothèse* :

*Supposer que (et subj.)* indique le Robert, la phrase correcte :

> ♦ Supposons que X et Y **soient** des espaces de Banach.

Et la source *[CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/supposer)*

> ♦ *Supposons que + subj.* : Supposons encore qu'il s'**agisse** d'une série d'expériences ayant pour objet de déterminer comment la tension de la vapeur d'eau varie avec la température du liquide générateur (Cournot, Fond. connaiss., 1851, p. 65).
>
> ♦ *En supposant que + **ind.** ou **subj***. : Le P. Bougeant échappait à l'argument, en supposant que les bêtes **étaient** des démons (Renan, Avenir sc., 1890, p. 512).

**B -** [*Source*](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070711120425AANTLJ0&p=supposons%20que)
Mais lorsque que la supposition porte sur le passé, sur un fait avéré, l'indicatif (ou même le conditionnel) est de mise, car on émet une hypothèse sur l'origine des faits ou des objets et non sur leur existence propre :

> Pourquoi supposez-vous que nous **avons fait** la guerre ? (Vercors, le silence de la mer, p 70).

.... et même l'impératif :

> Suppose qu'elle **mange** ta part de gâteau !

Comment: « indique le Robert » ?

Comment: Extrait du § 1.1  ... - SUPPOSER QUE (et subj.) « Supposer qu'on ait un pépin » (Aymé)....

Comment: @dragon > [le Robert](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaires_Le_Robert) et [le Larousse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Petit_Larousse) sont 2 éditeurs de dictionnaires très connus, en tout cas en Belgique et en France. Ils sont donc régulièrement repris comme référence. J'imagine que ton interrogation venait de là.

Comment: Dans le contexte des mathématiques, l'indicatif est bien plus courant. Et au passage l'emploi de la proposition infinitive que tu cites est très différent de l'emploi sus-mentionné.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez -- Le coté hypothèse avérée *vs* réalité m'avait échappé. Réponse complétée. Ce serait à vérifier avec votre remarque sur les mathématiques, car une hypothèse réclame le subjonctif ! Cela ne viendrait-il de l'emploi du subjonctif  en voie de disparition à l'oral ?

Comment: @dragon J'ai proposé une réponse dédiée aux mathématiques dans la réponse http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11509/en-math%c3%a9matiques-supposons-que-est-il-suivi-du-subjonctif-ou-de-lindicatif

Comment: En revanche, n'utilise-on pas avec le subjunctive pour le verbe « observer » ? Par exemple, je pense on doit dire « Observons que X et Y **sont** des espaces de Banach. » au lieu de « Observons que X et Y **soient** des espaces de Banach. » Puisque cette fois nous aurions la certitude avec « observer ».

Comment: @dragon  L'étymologie du mot subjonctif : du latin *subjunctivus* « attaché sous..., subordonné » ; il n'y a pas de condition, pas d'hypothèse, pas de supposition mais un constat, on observe un *être* (ou un objet comme *étant* tangible) donc **sont** s'impose... utiliser *soient* sonne déjà mal à l'oreille, mais nie même le fait même d'observer qui est un constat : *nous observons/constatons que ... est/sont ...* .